# Data filtering Javascript (Nested dictionary and arrays)

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js, filter, django-rest-framework

I`m trying to figure out how js filter() works.

I have an API, which returns something like this:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Category 1",
        "items": [
            {
                "name": "Vacancy item #1",
                "location": "Los Angeles",
                "overview": "Lorem ipsum",
                "get_absolute_url": "/careers/vacancy-item-1/"
            },
            {
                "name": "Vacancy item #2",
                "location": "Los Angeles",
                "overview": "Lorem ipsum",
                "get_absolute_url": "/careers/vacancy-item-2/"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Category 2",
        "items": [
            {
                "name": "Vacancy item #3",
                "location": "Washington D.C",
                "overview": "Lorem ipsum",
                "get_absolute_url": "/careers/vacancy-item-3/"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to filter this data based on the select value of the form. I`m working on the VUE.JS and Django.

And this is my JS code

```
filteredItems() {
                let vacancycategories = this.listData,
                    city = this.city,
                    category = this.category


                if (city && city.length > 0) {
                    vacancycategories = vacancycategories.filter((cat) => {

                         cat.items = cat.items.filter((vacancy) => {
                            return vacancy.location.indexOf(city) !== -1
                        })
                            return cat
                    })
                } 

                if (category && category.length > 0) {
                    vacancycategories = vacancycategories.filter((cat) => {
                        return cat.name.indexOf(category) !== -1
                    })
                }  
                return vacancycategories
            }
```

The category part is working as expected. But when I try to filter location fields, it's not working properly. The first selected option works normal but then when you select another option it returns an empty list.

Comment: _"I have an API, which is smth like this"_ - That's not an "API", that's an array of objects

Comment: You need to be clearer with what you want.. What do you mean with filtering location. Should you still get all categories and just remove the locations that doesnt match or should you just get the categories which has a location that matches? And in that case should all locations still be in the items array or jus tthe ones with a matching location?

Comment: @Millenjo I want to filter only vacancies with matching locations and categories. If the category doesn't have a related location it should disappear. I hope it's clear. I`m not a native English speaker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

every filter function need to return the boolean value.

Inner filter function is fine, But the outer filter function need to change.
Following changes should work.

```
vacancycategories = vacancycategories.filter(cat => {
  return (
    cat.items.filter(vacancy => {
      return vacancy.location.indexOf(city) !== -1;
    }).length > 0
  );
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now my filter is working on the location filters. But there is another issue with the categories. I mean when I try to filter with locations, data turns the whole category which has that location too. I need only to show exact locations in the category.